# Spring cloud stream: As a producer with requiredGroups defined can i specify a routingKey for the queue that will be created?

Tags: spring-cloud-stream, spring-cloud-stream-binder

I could not find anything in the documentation regarding my issue. If it is there and I missed it, please point it out to me.

I have a RabbitMQ message producer service using Spring Cloud Stream, and my configuration is as follows:

```yaml
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        outputSink-out-0:
          destination: foo
          producer:
            requiredGroups: bar
```

The above configuration creates my `foo` exchange in RabbitMQ and a `bar` queue with a routing key of `#`. My question is, how can I configure a specific routing key, such as `test.#`, for the `bar` queue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See the documentation: https://docs.spring.io/spring-cloud-stream/docs/current/reference/html/spring-cloud-stream-binder-rabbit.html#rabbit-prod-props

`spring.cloud.stream.rabbit.bindings.outputSink-out-0.producer.binding-routing-key=...`

> **bindingRoutingKey**

> The routing key with which to bind the queue to the exchange (if bindQueue is true). Can be multiple keys - see bindingRoutingKeyDelimiter. For partitioned destinations, -n is appended to each key. Only applies if requiredGroups are provided and then only to those groups.

> Default: #.